# MongoDB query for field checking for a percentage of words in a list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I am trying to come up with a bit of a fuzzy search against a field in a mongodb document.  If I have say 6 keywords that I am searching for say for example,

['red','crisp','sweet', 'crunchy', 'pie','durable'] and I am search a field with a description of an apple variety I want to return all apples that have any 4 of the 6 key words that I am searching for.   How would you accomplish that using MongoDB?

Here are two example document just for reference

```
{
    name: "Golden Delicious",
    description: "Golden Delicious is a large, yellowish-green skinned cultivar and very sweet to the taste. It is prone to bruising and shriveling, so it needs careful handling and storage. It is a favorite for salads, apple sauce, and apple butter."
}

{
    name: "Jonagold",
    description: "Jonagold is a cultivar of apple which was developed in 1953 in New York State Agricultural Experiment Station of Cornell University's College of Agriculture and Life Sciences, a cross between the crisp Golden Delicious and the blush-crimson Jonathan. They form a large sweet fruit with a thin skin. "
}
```

Comment: Could you post sample document ?

Comment: I went and added a couple sample documents just to help visualize the question.

Comment: Checking if 4 to 6 words match would be possible but you need to normalize the way you store `description`. So it would be a way easier if you could store description as an array of words (lowercase) like ``descriptionWords`: ["golden", "delicious"] ...`. Is that possible in your case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing with this a bit I was able to come up with a way to look for a specific number of matches using a Regex.   This is what I came up with

```
db.getCollection('apples').find({
description: {
    $regex: '((red|crisp|sweet|crunchy|pie|durable).*?){4}',
    $options: 'i'
}
```

})